WhatsApp Business API Access Token Issue – Account Blocked When Generating Long-Lived Token
We are integrating WhatsApp Cloud API for our app through the Business API Gateway. Here's what we have done so far:
Successfully generated a short-lived access token via the Graph API.
Used the token, version, and ID for API calls, which worked fine.
Meta approved our app review request.
However, the issue arises when we attempt to generate a long-lived (or permanent) access token. After making the request, our account gets temporarily blocked or restricted.
Does anyone know why this might be happening or what steps we need to take to avoid the restriction when generating a long-lived access token?
We're following Meta's guidelines for generating access tokens.
Short-lived tokens work fine, but the issue is specific to the long-lived token generation.
We've made sure all API calls adhere to the required permissions and scopes.
Any guidance or insights would be appreciated.
